# Return all lines following a matched date and time up, but not including the next date and time?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I'm trying to grab a snippet of text from a file that exists between two lines. Specifically I need to be able to grab a line and all the following lines up until another specific line.

For example, the Raw file would contain something like this:

```
Aug 23, 2011 10:31:35 AM This is the start of the text.
     This is more Text.
This is another line
This is another line
     This is more.
Aug 23, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.
This is another line
     This is more Text.
This is another line
     This is another line
     This is more.
Aug 24, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.
This is another line
     This is more Text.
This is another line
     This is another line
     This is more.
```

And I need it to parse through and return:

```
Aug 23, 2011 10:31:35 AM This is the start of the text.
     This is more Text.
This is another line
This is another line
     This is more.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on the method to implement this?

Comment: go and read: [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) this is what you need

Comment: simple readline loop, stops at line containing `next in the series`

Comment: Edit your question with what you have tried and people will be happy to help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

s = '''Aug 23, 2011 10:31:35 AM This is the start of the text.
      This is more Text.
This is another line
This is another line
      This is more.
Aug 23, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.
This is another line
      This is more Text.
This is another line
      This is another line
      This is more.
Aug 24, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.
This is another line
      This is more Text.
This is another line
      This is another line
      This is more. '''


months = '(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)'
ch = '%s \d\d?, \d{4} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d (?:AM|am|PM|pm)' % months


regx = re.compile('%s.*?(?=%s|\Z)' % (ch,ch), re.DOTALL)

for x in regx.findall(s):
    print repr(x)
    print
```

result

```
'Aug 23, 2011 10:31:35 AM This is the start of the text.\n      This is more Text.\nThis is another line\nThis is another line\n      This is more.\n'

'Aug 23, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.\nThis is another line\n      This is more Text.\nThis is another line\n      This is another line\n      This is more.\n'

'Aug 24, 2011 10:41:00 AM This is the next in the series.\nThis is another line\n      This is more Text.\nThis is another line\n      This is another line\n      This is more. '
```

Yes, you'll have to learn the regex tool (module `re`)

update: a minimum of explanations:

parens `(...)` define a group
without `?:`, it is a capturing group
`(?:......)` is a non capturing group

`(?=....)` means **after this point, there must be a portion of string matching what is symbolised after `?=` , but this portion isn't captured: that's the way to obtain a stop of the regex motor just before this portion, without capturing it; that allows too, and it is the more important, the regex motor to match again from the beginning of this stopping portion, otehrwise the latter would be consumed too

`re.DOTALL` is to make the symbol . (the dot) to match ALL the characters, comprised '\n' , which is not the case without this flag

Comment: regex has a little bit of a steep learning curve, but there are many great tutorials (e.g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for it out there and it is very very powerful.  One thing that I have always gotten into a habit of doing, though, is heavily commenting any regex I use that is even slightly complicated, otherwise I will come back in a couple of months and have to decipher what I originally wrote.

Comment: @Vorticity Very pertinent remark. I don't think enough to do that, I decide to make my resolution to recall this advice in the future. Instead of upvoting this comment of yours, I've just upvoted your interesting answer in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7133977/datetime-print-as-seconds/7134020#7134020) in which I learned the existence of ``datetime.timedelta.total_seconds()``